# Problema al subir un archivo con nodejs multer express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, multer

como estan estoy haciendo una api donde necesito subir un posteo, el cual tiene una imagen. estoy unsando Express y multer para realizarlo

pongo el codigo que tengo

Este es el código que uso para arrancar la aplicación.

```
import express from "express";
import TaskRoutes from './routes/task.routes';
import AuthRoutes from './routes/auth.routes';
import PostRoutes from './routes/post.routes';
import CategoryRoutes from './routes/category.routes'
import morgan from "morgan";
import cors from 'cors';


const app = express();
//settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

//middlewares
app.use(cors())
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//static Files
app.use('/public', express.static(`${__dirname}/storage/imgs`))



//routes
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.json({message: 'welcome to my application'});
})

app.use('/api/tasks', TaskRoutes);
app.use('/api/auth', AuthRoutes);
app.use('/api/post', PostRoutes);
app.use('/api/category', CategoryRoutes);


export default app;
```

Este es el código del controller que utilizo.

```
export const createPost = async (req,res) => {
    try{
        console.log(req.file);
        const newPost = new Post ({
            description: req.body.description,
            socialLink: req.body.socialLink,
            usuario: req.userId,
            category: req.body.category
        });

        if(req.file){
            const{filename} = req.file
            newPost.setImgUrl(filename)
        }

        const postSaved = await newPost.save();
        res.json(postSaved)
        
    }catch(error){
        res.status(500).json({
            message: error.message || "algo ocurrio mal al Crear una tarea."
        })
    }
```

la funcion setImgUrl la creo en el modelo y es la siguiente

```
postSchema.methods.setImgUrl = function setImgUrl(filename){
    this.imgUrl = `${'http://localhost'}:${'3000'}/public/${filename}`
}

export default model('Post', postSchema);
```

este es el la funcion de multer.

```
import multer from "multer"

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './storage/imgs')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
      cb(null, uniqueSuffix + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
  })
  
  const upload = multer({ storage })

  module.exports = upload
```

y por ultimo el codigo en el router.

```
import { Router } from "express";

import * as  postCtrl from '../controllers/post.controller';
import * as verify from '../middlewares/verifytoken'
import upload from '../middlewares/multer'

const router = Router();

router.post('/', verify.verifyToken, upload.single('image') ,postCtrl.createPost,)

router.get('/', verify.verifyToken, postCtrl.findAllPost);

router.get('/:id', );

router.delete('/:id', );

router.put('/:id',);
```

cuando lo ejecuto, no tengo problema. guarda en la basae de datos normalmente y guarda el enlace de la imagen y todo, el problema lo tengo que cuando intento abrir la imagen en el navegador con el link que se guarda en la base de datos, no obtengo la imagen sino, que dice que no existe la ruta donde se guardo.

[esta es la respuesta de la api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/div5p.png)

[y esto es lo que sale en el navegador cuando intento abrir la imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYkDq.png)

Comment: El enlace queda almacenado en la base de datos... pero queda almacenado el archivo en la ruta mencionada? (`./storage/imgs`)?

Comment: si, tambien queda almacenado en la ruta ./storage/imgs

Comment: Entonces creo que el problema puede estar aqui: `app.use('/public', express.static(\`${__dirname}/storage/imgs\`))`... depende como tengas la estructura del proyecto esa ruta podría no ser valida... ya la validaste? que esta ruta completa `"${__dirname}/storage/imgs"` si sea la esperada?

Comment: como hago para validar si esa ruta esta completa?

Comment: Puedes hacer un `console.log` a ese valor para saber que ruta genera

Comment: Gracias maestro, me solucionaste el problema. Llevo todo el tratando de ver que era y era eso... estaba mal al ruta. No se como agradecerte! muchas gracias de verdad

Comment: Con mucho gusto ;)